# Showing Master in UISplitViewController by default using swift

Tags: ios, uikit, swift

I want to initialize my application to show the master, instead of the detail, while using UISplitViewController using Xcode 6, and swift.

The problem - the delegate that was used for it till now is deprecated...

How can I, using swift, initialize the master view?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UISplitViewController in portrait on iPhone shows detail VC instead of master](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875618/uisplitviewcontroller-in-portrait-on-iphone-shows-detail-vc-instead-of-master)